# Solve for $x$ without using a calculator.

Tags: calculus, exponential-function

How can I solve for $x$
$$3e^{-2x}-6e^{-x}=72$$

If someone can go step by step and do the problem, it would be really appreciable.

Answer (score 7):

Substitute $e^{-x}=t$.

Now, Note that since $e^{-2x}=\left( e^{-x} \right)^2$, we have that  $$3e^{-2x}-6e^{-x}-72=0 \iff 3t^2-6t-72=0 \iff 3(t+4)(t-6)=0$$
From factorization. Since $t>0$, we have that $e^{-x}=t=6$.

So $-x=\ln 6$, or $x=-\ln 6$.

Comment: Guess that's the expected answer, but does it really count for `without using a calculator` ;-)

Comment: @dxiv Yes, why don't you think it doesn't? It doesn't ask to find the decimal expansion of $-\ln 6$. I think I'm missing something.

Comment: I wasn't totally serious (+1), but then if I otherwise proved that the equation has one unique solution, I wouldn't expect *that* to count for an answer, though without a calculator it's just as fuzzily defined as $\ln 6\,$.

Comment: @dxiv OK, I'll think on that.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: substitute $e^{-x} = t$ to obtain a quadratic equation in t.